# How Skoch's resizing system works?

Tags: image, zend-framework, zend-form, image-resizing

I'm using http://eliteinformatiker.de/2011/09/02/thumbnails-upload-and-resize-images-with-zend_form_element_file/ to resize my images in Zend Framework.

But actually, it doesn't work on `receive()`.

My code:

My Zend Form

```
class Application_Form_Admin_Photos_Ajout extends Zend_Form
{
   public function init()
    {        


        /**
         * FILE
         */
        $this->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
        $maxsize = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // Premier chiffre en MB
        $file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('path');
        $file->setLabel("Choisissez l'image");
        $file->setMaxFileSize($maxsize);
        $file->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
        $file->addValidator('Size', false, $maxsize);
        $file->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,png,gif');
        $file->setRequired(true);
        $this->addElement($file);



        /**
         * LEGENDE
         */
[...]


        /**
         * SUBMIT
         */
[...]
    }

}
```

MyController:

```
    if ($request->isPost())
    {
        if ($form->isValid($request->getPost()))
        {
            $file = pathinfo($form->path->getFileName());
            $path = Zend_Registry::get('config')->imgPath . uniqid() . time() . '.' . $file['extension'];
            $form->getElement('path')->addFilter('Rename', array('target' => $path,'overwrite' => true));
            $filterChain = new Zend_Filter();
            // Create the original one
            $filterChain->appendFilter(new Skoch_Filter_File_Resize(array(
                'directory' => Zend_Registry::get('config')->imgPath,
                'width' => 10000,
                'height' => 10000,
                'keepSmaller' => true
            )));
            // Create a medium image with at most 350x200 pixels
            $filterChain->appendFilter(new Skoch_Filter_File_Resize(array(
                'directory' => Zend_Registry::get('config')->thumbPath,
                'width' => 350,
                'height' => 200,
                'keepRatio' => true,
            )));
            $form->getElement('path')->addFilter($filterChain);
            if (!$form->path->receive())
                $this->_redirect('/admin/menu/menu');
        }
    }
```

Any solution ?

Thank you.

---

**I found.**

Replace this in your Zend Form :

```
$file->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
```

by,

```
$file->addValidator('Count', false, 2);
```

where `2` means that your Zend Form accepts 2 files max. (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.file.transfer.validators.html#zend.file.transfer.validators.count)

An other solution, simply **remove** the line,

```
$file->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
```

And this, it's not very useful :

```
 $filterChain->appendFilter(new Skoch_Filter_File_Resize(array(
            'directory' => Zend_Registry::get('config')->imgPath,
            'width' => 10000,
            'height' => 10000,
            'keepSmaller' => true
        )));
```

Comment: Can you add answers to stackoverflow already (I am not sure if new users can do it)? If yes, copy your solution to the answer area and **accept your own answer**. That’s the stackoverflow way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add answer found by you so the people know that this question is answered.

**I found.**

Replace this in your Zend Form :

```
$file->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
```

by,

```
$file->addValidator('Count', false, 2);
```

where 2 means that your Zend Form accepts 2 files max. (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.file.transfer.validators.html#zend.file.transfer.validators.count)

An other solution, simply remove the line,

```
$file->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
```

And this, it's not very useful :

```
$filterChain->appendFilter(new Skoch_Filter_File_Resize(array(
            'directory' => Zend_Registry::get('config')->imgPath,
            'width' => 10000,
            'height' => 10000,
            'keepSmaller' => true
        )));
```